# insert and update data from table 1 to table 2 with match id

Tags: mysql

Here's my problem: I have two example tables below, I tried update and insert from table one to table two based matching id. but not work. and when not exist add to table 2

Table 1

```
   ID   DESC
1. 1    one
2. 2    two
3. 3    three
4. 4    four
```

Table 2

```
   ID   DESC
1. 1    ones
2. 2    
3. 3    three

INSERT INTO 
notif_test(ntfy_ttl,ntfy_desc,ntfy_typ,beg_dt,del_nbr,crt_ts,crt_nbr,
upd_ts,upd_nbr) select
ntfy_ttl,ntfy_desc,ntfy_typ,beg_dt,del_nbr,crt_ts,crt_nbr,upd_ts,upd_nbr
from notif_dump
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ntfy_desc = VALUES(ntfy_desc)
```

Comment: I would think you need an `Update` for those rows that exist in both tables and an `Insert` for those rows that don't exist in `Table 2`.

Comment: Did you consider using foreign keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? Also you may want to read about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: i don't get it.,

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor Google it so you'll get it.

Comment: @Eric i don't ask here, if i get from google..

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor Have you researched on what is suggested?  Part of solution to solve problem is to do some research.  "I don't get it" doesn't help much.  Does it mean you have read, but still don't understand, or you haven't done anything at all?

Comment: Good reference how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data seems  you are  looking for an updated  of values where DESC is  nulls

```
update table1 a 
inner join table2 b
on a.id = b.id
set a.desc = b.desc
where a.desc is null
```